# How to highlight a word in an HTML list form a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, string

I have a given word (from an Input) that I'll use to search from a list of objects and return the strings if it has the given word. I already did this and I'm displaying it on a list, but I need to highlight with red the first time the given word appears on the string.

This is my code so far:

```
function consultaCompras(){
    let palabra=document.getElementById("buscarConsultas").value.trim();

    while (document.getElementById("listaResultado").hasChildNodes()){
        document.getElementById("listaResultado").removeChild(document.getElementById("listaResultado").lastChild);
    }

    let mostrarString=sistema.realizarConsulta(palabra);

    if(mostrarString.length==0){
        alert("No hay compras con la palabra ingresada.")
    }else{
        for(let j=0;j<mostrarString.length;j++){

            let nodoLi=document.createElement("LI");
            let nodoTexto=document.createTextNode(mostrarString[j]);
            nodoLi.appendChild(nodoTexto);
            document.getElementById("listaResultado").appendChild(nodoLi);
        }
    }
}
```

The variable "mostrarString" has an array with all the strings with the given word, and then with the for loop I'll get all the strings and I'll add them to the list.

That works ok, but I don't know how to change the color of the given word the first time it appears on a string.

Comment: create a reproducible example will help people to do the debugging.

Comment: The thing is the task is pretty large, I'll have to share the HTML and another JS file with the Classes (two of them) to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something along the lines of:

```
for(let i = 0; i < mostrarString.length; i++) {
    //break each sentence down to its own array of words
    let splitString = mostrarString[i].split(" "); 
    let rebuiltString = '';

    for(let j = 0; j < splitString.length; j++) {
        //if the word matches palabra variable and is the first occurrence in the sentence
        if(splitString[j] === palabra && splitString.indexOf(splitString[j]) === j){
            //wrap it in a span tag
            rebuiltString += `<span style="color:red">${splitString[j]}</span>`
        } else {
            //otherwise add to new string as is
            rebuiltString += splitString[j]
        }
        //add a space except after last word
        if(i !== splitString.length - 1) {
            rebuiltString += " "
        }
    }
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    //set the string as the innerhtml so the span tag renders
    newItem.innerHTML = rebuiltString; 
    document.getElementById('listaResultado').append(newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this may need some tweaking because I'm not 100% on your variables (is mostrarString an array of words?) but in the for loop add:

```
if(mostrarString.indexOf(mostrarString[j]) === j) {
    nodoLi.setAttribute("style","color:red;")
}
```

Comment: Yes, mostrarString is an array of strings. I get what you try to do, but I need to change the color of the word that matches the given word from the string, not the whole string. So, I have an array of strings (mostrarString) that they all have the given word on them, but now I need to change the color of the given word (and still show the full string, but with the given word on red the first time it appears on the string).

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something like this

here is an exemple

```html
<body>
<div id="banner-message">
  </div>
  <script>
    input=" beautiful"
    var mostrarString=["spanish is a beautiful language javascript is a beautiful language"," is a beautiful language javascript is c# beautiful language" ]
    function findmatch(input , str){
      mod= str.replace(input, `<span style="color:red"> ${input}</span>`)
      return   `<p> ${mod} </p>`
    }
    if(mostrarString.length==0){
            alert("No hay compras con la palabra ingresada.")
        }else{
            for(let j=0;j<mostrarString.length;j++){
                modifiedtext=findmatch(input,mostrarString[j])
                var nodoLi=document.createElement("div")
                 nodoLi.innerHTML=(`${modifiedtext}`);
                document.getElementById("banner-message").appendChild(nodoLi);
            }
        }
    
      </script>
</body>
```